# send confirmation mail via ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to send a confirm registration mail. I don't want to use the SMTPs for gmail or windows Live as it is not legal and can not be used for those type of purposes.

Is there any mailing service that is accessible by code which can satisfy my requirements in a legal way?

I'm using ASP.NET Framework 3.5.

Comment: What do you mean 'it is not legal'? It's entirely valid to send an email from your gmail/google apps account.

Comment: @p.campbell - Probably terms and conditions of gmail and windows Live do not allow commercial use.

Comment: You need to get in touch with an ISP and pay for an SMTP server.

Comment: or maybe it's a legal issue specific to OP's country.

Comment: Yes they are gonna block my Email account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SMTP server you use will likely depend on where you are running your code.

Locally (i.e. developing on Visual Studio), you should use an SMTP server which you know will relay mail from your IP address.  This is normally your ISP's SMTP server.  Check with them for specifics ( but a couple of good guesses might be `smtp.yourisp.com` or `mail.yourisp.com` ).

In a corporate environment, you should be able to use your company's SMTP server.  Check with your tech people for specifics.

In a public Internet hosted environment, you can either use your own SMTP server or one provided with your hosting package.  Again, you should be able to get this from your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

Get your own domain and hosted mail server.  Usually you can find them for $10/mo or less

Comment: And if my own hosted mail server uses the gmail mail server?

Answer (score 0):

You could try leveraging something like [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/pricing/). If your audience is small enough, you could even use their free service.

Further Reading:
http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/sts/1.0/sendemail.func.php

Comment: Actually i tried MailChimp for a week and configured the API for my application but I found that it is not flexible enough for that purpose "sending confirmation mail" for many reasons, one of them is that MailChimp forced me to include unsubscribe link in my mail which I don't need and doesn't make any sense to be existing at all!!

Comment: In that case, I 2nd @Paul Alan Taylor

Comment: Also forced me to send campaign using only lists, I can not choose one mail to send confirmation mail, forcing me to send to the whole list which is not ideal for my case.